# Coverity Scan Build Tool C/C++ instructions: sysctl vsyscall=emulate

Tags: coverity

The *Troubleshooting* section of the [Coverity Scan Build Tool C/C++ instructions](https://scan.coverity.com/download?tab=cxx) states:

> - **WARNING:** Linux users on kernel version 4.8.x and newer will need to apply a sysctl parameter to support our binaries. Without this
>     parameter, our binaries will not work on your platform. This is a
>     known issue which we will address with a future release.
>
>   ```
>   # sysctl vsyscall=emulate
>   ```

The above command fails on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with kernel 4.15.0:

```
# uname -r
4.15.0-20-generic
# 
# sysctl vsyscall=emulate
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/vsyscall: No such file or directory
#
```

Should I disregard these instructions? Use a different command?

Answer (score 0):

The Coverity Build Tool for C/C++ seems to be working just fine on my computer without applying this sysctl parameter.

Either the warning does not apply to the current version of the Coverity Build Tool (version 2017.07) or the sysctl parameter is not required on some recent versions of the kernel, such as kernel 4.15.0 as shipped with Ubuntu 18.04.